# Issue comparing letters in a string [Assembly]

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I'm trying to create a program which iterates through a string and checks to see if it is a palindrome.

The word I am currently testing is *racecar*, but when I run the following code, it automatically decides that the first and last values aren't the same.

Is this just a case of entering the wrong registers into the loop, or is there something more than that?

```
main proc
mov edi, SIZEOF myWord- TYPE myWord ;length of string - type of data
mov ecx, LENGTHOF myWord/ 2  ;loop (N / 2) times
mov esi,OFFSET myWord ;beginning of string

checkWord:
mov al,[esi]
cmp [esi+edi],al
jne wordIsNotAPalindrome

add esi,TYPE myWord
sub edi,TYPE myWord
loop checkWord

mov edx, offset wordIsAPalindrome
call WriteString
exit
main endp
```

Declaration for myWord:

```
myWord BYTE "racecar", 0
```

Edit:

I just made a few adjustments, and this is what I have now:

```
main proc
mov edi, SIZEOF myWord- TYPE myWord
mov ecx, LENGTHOF myWord/ 2
mov esi,OFFSET myWord

checkWord:
mov al, SIZEOF myWord
mov al,[esi]
cmp [myWord+edi],al
jne wordIsNotAPalindrome

add esi,TYPE myWord
sub edi,TYPE myWord
loop checkWord

mov esi, offset wordIsAPalindrome
call WriteString
call Crlf
call Crlf
exit
main endp
```

It loops now correctly, and when I do Step Over, it proceeds to make it until wordIsAPalindrome. The problem is, this is the output:

> Θµ#
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Can you post the declaration of "myWord"? Click "edit" under your question and paste the code.

Comment: What is the value of `SIZEOF myWord`? Does it (to name just a possible cause) include the null byte at the end?

Comment: @RadLexus Just updated the question. I made an adjustment based off of your question, and now it loops successfully. Although now there's a diff issue. Fix one thing, break something else.

Comment: Kudos for trying to keep your source code minimal, but now we may need to know what `presetWord` is, and what it's for.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Irvine](http://math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/cs221/handouts/procedures.pdf)'s `WriteString`, it takes the offset of the string from `EDX` register, not `ESI`, so :

```
     ▼
mov edx, offset wordIsAPalindrome
call WriteString
```

Comment: I just noticed that while I was testing something out. Whoops.